# customize url on django

Tags: python, django

I would like to set up a url path that takes into account
any string consisting of ASCII letters or numbers, the hyphen or character and also a period.
For example: **localhost:8000/mysite/toto-25b.ko**

How to set this up with re_path ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
re_path(r'^mysite/(?P<account>[\w\d\-\.]+)', views.account, name='account'),
```